# JS array not returning index values of specific text even though text exists

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexing, lookup

fairly new to JS. I have an HTML table with columns in this order: Continent, Country, etc... So far, I have working code that reads the HTML table to create an array for all countries, and then removes duplicates. I also have an array that looks up the continent in the HTML table for each element of the countries array.

My issue is that I can't seem to lookup all the indexes in the continents array for a certain value (e.g. "Africa"). Here is my code:

```
//Step 1: create an array to hold each country's continent. The 'countries' array was 
previously created. 
 
   var continents = [];
   for (const element of countries){
     console.log(element);

      var contin = []; 
      for (j = 0 ; j < data.rows.length; j++){
         if (data.rows[j].cells[1].innerHTML.indexOf(element) >= 0) 
         contin.push(data.rows[j].cells[0].innerHTML);
         }
         continents.push(contin);
}

//Step 2: Create a function that can look up all indexes in the continents array for a certain value.
        function getAllIndexes(arr, val) {
          var indexes = [], i;
          for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
              if (arr[i] === val)
              indexes.push(i);
          return indexes;
        }

//Step 3: Run the function to get all index values where continents array = "Africa"
         indexesAfrica = getAllIndexes(continents, "Africa");
         alert(indexesAfrica);
```

When I run the function, it returns a blank. I've tested the function on other arrays and it works. For example, this code returns the correct indexes of "1,3":

```
var funArr = ["test", "Africa", "Hello","Africa"];
indexesAfrica = getAllIndexes(funArr, "Africa");
alert(indexesAfrica);
```

This makes me think something is wrong with my continents array? The continents array shows the correct list of array items when I alert(continents), but I can't seem to lookup anything in it. Thoughts?

Comment: You need to give us the ```continents``` array data. Better to create a complete example which includes the result and/or any error

Comment: Easiest way to share this? My HTML table is very long

Comment: Ok so I'm seeing from the console that the data looks different in my continents array compared to the countries array. Viewing 'countries' in console looks like this:

0: "Algeria"
1: "Angola"
2: "Benin"
3: "Botswana"
4: "Burkina Faso"
5: "Burundi"
6: "Cameroon"
7: "Cape Verde"
etc...

Whereas 'continents' looks like this:

0: (3) ["Africa", "Africa", "Africa"]
1: ["Africa"]
2: (3) ["Africa", "Africa", "Africa"]
3: (3) ["Africa", "Africa", "Africa"]
4: (2) ["Africa", "Africa"]
5: ["Africa"]
6: (4) ["Africa", "Africa", "Africa", "Africa"]
7: ["Africa"]
etc....

Comment: So I think I understand what's happening. My continents array is actually an array of arrays, instead of a single array. Will keep investigating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was going to leave this as a comment, but it seems like it would solve your situation and maybe help teach something. Why have them as 2 separate arrays? It's not very scalable. If you sort your country array at all, you'll lose the association to the continent.  Better to couple them in an array of objects, which is easily filtered (like if you only want to show countries that are in Africa).

```js
let countries = ["Algeria", "Angola", "Benin", "Botswana", "Burkina Faso", "Burundi", "Cameroon", "Cape Verde", "USA"]
let data = document.querySelector('table');

let globe = countries.map(country => { // using map, we can transform each incoming country into a country/continent object
  let continent = 'N/A'; // just so we have somethign in case we dont find a continent
  [...data.rows].forEach(row => { // data is the table, rows are the <tr> tags, but we need to make it iterable for the loop, so we wrap it in a spread [...] 
    if (row.cells[1].innerText.trim() === country) continent = row.cells[0].innerText.trim();
  })
  return { country: country, continent: continent}; // we return an object back to our map
});
console.log(globe)

//Step 2: Run the function to get all index values where continents array = "Africa"

const africanCountries = globe.filter(e => e.continent === "Africa").map(e => e.country);
console.log(africanCountries)
```

```html
<table>
  <tr><td>Africa</td><td>Algeria</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Africa</td><td>Angola</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Africa</td><td>Benin</td></tr>
  <tr><td>North America</td><td>USA</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Africa</td><td>Botswana</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Africa</td><td>Burkina Faso</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Africa</td><td>Faso</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Africa</td><td>Burundi</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Africa</td><td>Cameroon</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Africa</td><td>Cape Verde</td></tr>
</table>
```

Update: to add the lat and long, you can tap into the index in map()

```
let globe = countries.map((country, index) => { // using map, we can transform each incoming country into a country/continent object
  let continent = 'N/A'; // just so we have somethign in case we dont find a continent
  [...data.rows].forEach(row => { // data is the table, rows are the <tr> tags, but we need to make it iterable for the loop, so we wrap it in a spread [...] 
    if (row.cells[1].innerText.trim() === country) continent = row.cells[0].innerText.trim();
  })
  return { 
     country: country, 
     continent: continent,
     lat: countryLat[index],
     long: countryLong[index]
   }; // we return an object back to our map
});
```

Comment: Great suggestion! I got this working; this idea makes more sense with what I'm trying to do next. I have three additional variables that are unique to each country, and that would make sense to store in this array of objects: latitude, longitude, and average temperature. 

Currently, these values are each in their own arrays (stored in same order as 'countries') called: 

'countryLat', 'countryLong', and 'countryTemp'

How could I push all of the values in each of these 3 arrays into your 'globe' array for each country?

Comment: is that data in the same table as country and continent?

Comment: No. Since there were multiple entries for some countries, I had to do some calculations for latitude, longitude, and avg temperature for each country. So up until now, I had 4 arrays: 'countries', 'countryLat', 'countryLong', and 'countryTemp'. Each array is the same length and in the same order (e.g. if Algeria was index number 3 in 'countries', then the corresponding index number in the other three arrays is also 3).

Comment: Ok looks like I figured it out. I just looped through and added a new property like this:

`for (j = 0 ; j < globe.length; j++){
         globe[j].lat = countryLat[j];
         }`

Comment: @carvalh3 - yes, but you can also tap into the original map() function index. See revised answer - the last part at the end